# multiple ckeditors with jquery ui-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to combine ckeditor 4.1 with jquery ui tab.

forums mentioned for hidden tab contents, since "contenteditable" attribute is usually turned to "false", therefore although the skin of the ckeditor is loaded, the editor content will usually be frozen in tab2, tab3.... and I have solved this problem by triggering this attribute to be "true" when clicking the tabs.

Unfortunately, although the contents are now editable, nearly 95% of the toolbar items are disabled!

How shall I initialize the customerized tool bar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy to reinitialize ckeditors like

```
ckeditor.init({
   'theme':'simple'
});
```

or simply you can put like this on each tab click

```
CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor'].setData('Enter Description');
```

here you are creating instance for 'ckeditor'